# How to manipulate the data after numpy.loadtxt?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io, matrix

I have raw data such as below. for example, We load text file which has 1st row has xlabel, 1st column is ylabel. lets call file name is '131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt'.

```
Y/X (mm),   0,  10, 20, 30, 40
686.6,  -5.02,  -0.417, 0,  100.627,    0
694.08, -5.02,  -4.529, -17.731,    -5.309, -3.535
701.56, 1.869,  -4.529, -17.731,    -5.309, -3.535
709.04, 1.869,  -4.689, -17.667,    -5.704, -3.482
716.52, 4.572,  -4.689, -17.186,    -5.704, -2.51 
724,    4.572,  -4.486, -17.186,    -5.138, -2.51
731.48, 6.323,  -4.486, -16.396,    -5.138, -1.933
738.96, 6.323,  -4.977, -16.396,    -5.319, -1.933
746.44, 7.007,  -4.251, -16.577,    -5.319, -1.688
753.92, 7.007,  -4.251, -16.577,    -5.618, -1.688
761.4,  7.338,  -3.514, -16.78, -5.618, -1.207
768.88, 7.338,  -3.514, -16.78, -4.657, -1.207
776.36, 7.263,  -3.877, -15.99, -4.657, -0.822
```

(Q1) As you can see the raw data, they has xlabel and ylabel in respectively 1st row, 1st column. If I use numpy.loadtxt function, How to split "xs" and "ys" ?

```
rawdata = numpy.loadtxt('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt')
xs, ys, data = func(rawdata)
```

Do I have to implement additional logic ? or is there any function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `np.loadtxt` can't handle that first row separately very well, so you have to do something clever.  I'll give two ways, the first is shorter, but the second is more straighforward

1) you could do this 'hack' by reading the first row as header *names*:

```
y_and_data = np.genfromtxt('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt', names=True, delimiter=',')
x = np.array(y_and_data.dtype.names[1:], int)
y = y_and_data['YX_mm']
data = y_and_data.view(np.float).reshape(-1, len(y_and_data.dtype))[:,1:]
```

2) But I recommend to just read the first line separately first, save it, and then open the rest with `loadtxt` (or `genfromtxt` as I've used and recommend):

```
with open('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = np.array(f.readline().split(',')[1:], int)
    y_and_data = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',')
y = y_and_data[:,0]
data = y_and_data[:,1:]
```

How it works, first open the file, and call it `f`:

```
with open('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt', 'r') as f:

    firstline = f.readline()           # read off the first line
    firstvalues = firstline.split(',') # split it on the comma
    xvalues = firstvalues[1:]          # and keep the all but the first elements
    x = np.array(xvalues, int)         # make it an array of integers (or float if you prefer)
```

Now that the first line has been read from `f` using `f.readline`, the remainder can be read with `genfromtxt`:

```
    y_and_data = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',')
```

Now, the other answers show how to split the rest:

```
y = y_and_data[:,0]       # the first column is the y-values
data = y_and_data[:,1:]   # the remaining columns are the data
```

And this is the output:

```
In [58]: with open('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt', 'r') as f:
   ....:     x = np.array(f.readline().split(',')[1:], int)
   ....:     y_and_data = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',')
   ....: y = y_and_data[:,0]
   ....: data = y_and_data[:,1:]
   ....: 

In [59]: x
Out[59]: array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])

In [60]: y
Out[60]: 
array([ 686.6 ,  694.08,  701.56,  709.04,  716.52,  724.  ,  731.48,
        738.96,  746.44,  753.92,  761.4 ,  768.88,  776.36])

In [61]: data
Out[61]: 
array([[  -5.02 ,   -0.417,    0.   ,  100.627,    0.   ],
       [  -5.02 ,   -4.529,  -17.731,   -5.309,   -3.535],
       [   1.869,   -4.529,  -17.731,   -5.309,   -3.535],
       [   1.869,   -4.689,  -17.667,   -5.704,   -3.482],
       [   4.572,   -4.689,  -17.186,   -5.704,   -2.51 ],
       [   4.572,   -4.486,  -17.186,   -5.138,   -2.51 ],
       [   6.323,   -4.486,  -16.396,   -5.138,   -1.933],
       [   6.323,   -4.977,  -16.396,   -5.319,   -1.933],
       [   7.007,   -4.251,  -16.577,   -5.319,   -1.688],
       [   7.007,   -4.251,  -16.577,   -5.618,   -1.688],
       [   7.338,   -3.514,  -16.78 ,   -5.618,   -1.207],
       [   7.338,   -3.514,  -16.78 ,   -4.657,   -1.207],
       [   7.263,   -3.877,  -15.99 ,   -4.657,   -0.822]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want `xs`, `ys`, and `data` in separate arrays, you can do this:

```
xs = np.array(open('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt').readline().split(',')[1:], int)
rawdata = numpy.loadtxt('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt', skiprows=1)
ys = rawdata[:, 0]
data = rawdata[:, 1:]
```

Note the `skiprows` keyword to ignore the first row of the file.

Comment: I don't think this is the format the OP has.  The second column doesn't contain Y data, it contains the first ylabel and then data.

Comment: You can't skip the first row, it has the x-data.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @bogatron's answer, you can pass the argument `unpack=True` to get `xs, ys, data` in one line:

```
xs, ys, data = numpy.loadtxt('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt', skiprows=1, unpack=True)
```